# Covariance between sample mean of two simple random samples

Tags: sampling, covariance, finite-population

Suppose that we have two simple random samples without replacement $A$ and $B$ from a population $P$ of size $N$ such that $B = P-A$ where $n$ is the size of $A$ and $m$ is the size of $B$.

I want to find the covariance between $\bar x_A, \bar x_B$

I have done the following:

$Cov(\bar x_A, \bar x_B) = Cov(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \frac{1}{m} \sum_{j=1}^m X_j) =\frac{1}{nm} \sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{j=1}^m Cov(X_i,X_j) = \frac{1}{nm} \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N Cov(X_i I_i ,X_j I_j)$

where $I_i, I_j$ are the indicator functions

$ = \frac{1}{nm} \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j=1}^N X_i X_j Cov(I_i ,I_j)$

And this is where I do not know how to proceed.

Comment: What do those "Indicator functions" indicate?

Comment: One technique is illustrated at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/477531.  However, have you noticed that the mean of $A$ determines the mean of $B$? Once you add the observation that the relationship is linear, you have established that the correlation is $-1.$ That leaves you to compute the variance of just one of the sample means, which you probably already know.